# Looping through a small SQL database infinitely in Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am fairly new to Python and am still learning things as I do them. I need to read an SQL database row by row (20 or 30 rows) and then loop back to the first row after I reach the end row.

I have tried using a for statement nested in an infinite loop but it only runs through the rows once.

```py
c.execute('''SELECT Tank_number, Pressure, Diameter, SG FROM Tank_Data''')

while True:

    for row in c:

        Tank_number = row[0]
        Pressure = row[1]   
        Diameter = row[2]
        SG = row[3]
```

I'm assuming this is a simple problem but I've been trying for a long time to do it. If I could somehow get an identifier for the current row it is on then I could set the row back to 1 if it reaches the final row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get an identifier for the current row, use enumerate:

```
while True:
    c.execute('''SELECT Tank_number, Pressure, Diameter, SG FROM Tank_Data''')
    for index, row in enumerate(c):
        Tank_number = row[0]
        Pressure = row[1]   
        Diameter = row[2]
        SG = row[3]
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Then the index of the row is saved in the variable `index` and you can do whatever you want with it. Also, this will keep calling `c.execute` refreshing the table.

Comment: I'd suggest adding a `time.sleep(0.5)` or something similar just after completing a cycle.